# Понять какие данные с сервера дают JsonNull retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

Хочу в коде вставить проверку на наличие данных в ответе сервера. Приходит такая ошибка:

```
System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonNull
```

вот возможные поля которые могут мне выдавать такое:

```
JsonObject app_data = response.body().getApp();
JsonObject applicant_data = response.body().getApplicant();
JsonObject consultant_data = response.body().getConsultant();
JsonObject photo_data = applicant_data.get("photo").getAsJsonObject();
```

при этом у меня поле `consultant` равно `null` и поле `photo` тоже `null`. Пробовал проверить так например:

```
if (!photo_data.isJsonNull())
```

но похоже это не сработало. Как можно проверить данные на входе, чтобы не получать таких ошибок?

Comment: А `POJO` использовать нельзя?

Comment: @woesss, не понял про `POJO`, можете пояснить?

Comment: Класс-модель, Вы же не вчера связались с ретрофитом уже пора бы запомнить.

Comment: @woesss, я не понял что вы хотите через класс-модель получать? jsonobject или что?

Comment: Если получать `JsonObject` - тогда зачем вообще `GsonConverter`? Есть `org.json` из SDK. _что вы хотите через класс-модель получать_ - я ничего не хочу, просто с моделью таких проблем нет.

Comment: суть в том что у меня только один такой запрос, и мне получается для него нужно сделать отдельную инициализацию ретрофита? просто я сейчас пытаюсь всеми известными и неизвестными мне способами чекнуть через условие что у меня null пришел, и пока не получается что-то :(

Comment: В методах, которые Вы вызываете на body ищите проблему (ака `getApp()`). Там ведь Вы тоже каким-то чудом возвращаете `JsonObject`. Разве стектрейс не туда указывает?

Comment: Прикол в том что я не могу найти указание стектрейса на определенную строку, он просто выводит инфу и все

Comment: Тогда ройте весь проект и везде, где Вы откуда-то берёте `JsonObject` по ключу, проверяйте безопасно ли он получен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала получаем элемент, его проверяем и приводим к нужному типу. Для примера:

```
JsonObject photo_data = null;

JsonElement jsonElement = applicant_data.get("photo");
if (jsonElement != null && jsonElement.isJsonObject()) {
    photo_data = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
}

// check photo_data non null and use
```

Comment: я обернул все в такую конструкцию как вы написали, но все-равно получаю эту ошибку, в чем может быть проблема не знаете?

Comment: Так Вам это надо сделать со всеми объектами - то есть все четыре строки в том же духе.

Comment: я сделал с каждым из объектов, и все-равно получаю ошибку

Comment: Какую - не NPE случаем?

Comment: та нет, все ту же)